# AngularJS nullable parameter missing in ASP.NET Web Service method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

I am calling an ASP.NET Web Service Method with a nullable optional paramter  from an AngularJS controller. It works fine if I provide the parameter value but don't work if the parameter value is not provided!! and shows he following error:

***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)***

and In details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: name.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

**Here is Web service Method:**

```
[WebMethod]
        public void GetAllStudents(string name)
        {
            IQueryable<Student> listStudents = dbContext.Students;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                listStudents = listStudents.Where(x => x.name.Contains(name));
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listStudents.ToList()));
        }
```

**Here is My Route Config:**

```
  $routeProvider.when("/students/:name?",
        {
            templateUrl: "Templates/Students.html",
            controller: "studentsController",

        })
```

**Here is My Controller:**

```
.controller("studentsController", function ($scope, $http, $route, $location, $routeParams) {
        $scope.message = "Student Page";

        $scope.studentSearch = function () {
            if ($scope.name) {
                $location.url("/students/" + $scope.name);
            }
            else {
                $location.url("/students");
            }
        }

        if ($routeParams.name) {
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "StudentService.asmx/GetAllStudents",
                params: { name: $routeParams.name }
            })
           .then(function (response) {
               $scope.students = response.data;
           })
        }
        else {
            $http.get("StudentService.asmx/GetAllStudents")
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.students = response.data;
            })
        }

    })
```

***Any Help please!!**

Comment: you want to pass parameter in every request ?

Comment: Yeh!! but by default parameter value should be null..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It works but looks a bit of ugly with two if statement successively**

```
if ($routeParams.name) {
                $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "StudentService.asmx/GetAllStudents",
                    params: { name: $routeParams.name }
                })
               .then(function (response) {
                   $scope.students = response.data;
               })
            }

    if ($routeParams.name == undefined) {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "StudentService.asmx/GetAllStudents",
            params: { name: ""}
        })
       .then(function (response) {
           $scope.students = response.data;
       })
    }
```

Comment: this will not send null  in Web service it will send  " " in param , you can do this as i suggest by do a check for undefined  for avoid code repetition

Answer (score 0):

instead of write if else statement just check that param before sending and assign null  if there is no value in that or if it is undefined

```
 $routeParams.name = (!angular.isUndefined($routeParams.name) && $routeParams.name != "")?$routeParams.name:"";

  $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "StudentService.asmx/GetAllStudents",
                params: { name: $routeParams.name }
            })
           .then(function (response) {
               $scope.students = response.data;
           })
        }
```

Comment: try updated answer, and please check your console for error might be in case of  $routeParams.name undefined

Comment: Nothing changed!! now even don't work for with Parameter!! Yes it is undefined..Now What to do??